# Tensorflow Multi-GPU reusing vs. duplicating?

Tags: python, tensorflow

To train a model on multiple GPUs one can create one set of variables on first GPU and reuse them (by `tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=device_num != 0)`) on other GPUs as in [cifar10_multi_gpu_train](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L169).

But I came across the [official CNN benchmarks](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/benchmark_cnn.py) where in local replicated setting they use new variable scope for each GPU (by `tf.variable_scope('v%s' % device_num)`). Since all variables are initialized randomly, [*post init op*](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/variable_mgr.py#L319) is used to copy values from `GPU:0` to others.

Both implementations then average gradients on CPU and back-propagate back the result (at least that is what I think since the benchmarks code is cryptic:)) - probably resulting in the same outcome.

What is then the difference between these two approaches and more importantly what is faster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that if you're reusing variables every iteration starts with a broadcast of the variables from their original location all GPUs, while if you're copying variables this broadcast is unnecessary, so not sharing should be faster.

The one downside of not sharing is that it's easier for a bug or numerical instability somewhere to lead to different GPUs ending up with different values for each variable.

Comment: I don't see how a numerical instability should lead to different values. If I use the same GPUs, their rounding errors should be the same and deterministic, right? Or how do you mean the numerical instability?

Comment: No, the rounding errors in reduction and convolutional ops are not deterministic and depend on internal multithreading